# How can I switch my "left ctrl" and "left alt" key on my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm working on a windows xp laptop at office. I have a standalone USB windows keyboard that I want to switch the "left ctrl" and "left alt" only on this keyboard.

1. I don't have any admin privileges on the laptop to run softwares to switch the keys
2. I often pair-programming with others, and they don't want the keys switched

So I'm looking for a way to switch the keys only on my own USB keyboard, is there any?

1. I know HHKB pro keyboard has some switches to switch keys, but that's too expensive
2. Is there any adapter to connect the keyboard and the laptop, that we can change the keys through it?
3. Can I modify the hardware of the keyboard to switch the keys, is it possible?

Comment: Depends how you want them switched and what type of keyboard it is.   I would buy a cheap $9.99 physically pry the keys off and switch them.  If the keyboard breaks your only out $10.  Put the other keyboard back when someone else uses it. (or just have 2 keyboards attached at once.)

Comment: I think OP wants to change more than just button appearances.